# what is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of the function $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

But, just to get across the idea of a generating function, here is how a generatingfunctionologist might answer the question: the nth Fibonacci number, $F_{n}$, is the coefficient of $x^{n}$ in the expansion of the function $\frac{x}{(1 − x − x^2)}$ as a power series about the origin.

I am reading a book about generating function, however, I got a little rusted about power series. could anyone give me a quick review about what the statement above is saying?

namely,

$F_{n}$, is the coefficient of $x_{n}$ in the expansion of the function $\frac{x}{(1 − x − x^2)}$ as a power series about the origin

Comment: You are looking for a power series $A$ such that $A(1-x-x^2)=x$.

Comment: @ Jorge Fernandez Hidalgo would you mind expand a little more on it?

Comment: The denominator tells you $F_n - F_{n-1} - F_{n-2} = 0$ while the numerator tells you that $F_0=0$ and (combined with the leading term of the denominator) that $F_1=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the power series
$$f(x) = F_0 + F_1 x + F_2 x^2 + \cdots$$
then the relation $F_{n+2} = F_n + F_{n+1}$ implies
$$x^2 f(x) + x f(x) - F_0 x = f(x) - F_0 - F_1 x.$$
(Write out each term as a power series, and combine terms.)
Rearranging and plugging in $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$ gives
$$(1-x-x^2) f(x) = x.$$

---

More detail:

\begin{align}
x^2 f(x) + x f(x)
&= (F_0 x^2 + F_1 x^3 + F_2 x^4 + \cdots) + (F_0 x + F_1 x^2 + F_2 x^3 + \cdots)
\\
&=F_0 x + (F_0+F_1)x^2 + (F_1+F_2)x^3 + (F_2+F_3)x^4+\cdots\\
&= F_0 x + F_2 x^2 + F_3 x^3 + F_4 x^4 + \cdots
\\
&= F_0 x - F_0 - F_1 x + (F_0 + F_1x + F_2x^2 + F_3 x^3 + \cdots)
\\
&= F_0 x - F_0 - F_1 x + f(x).
\end{align}

Comment: @ angryavian how did $F_{2}x^{2}$ become $x^{2}f(x)+xf(x)$? as I see you reaarange the terms from the first formula into the second formula.

Comment: @Tmm The series $f(x)$ has more terms, like $F_3 x^3 + F_4 x^4 + \cdots$

Comment: @ angryavian I hope you don't mind, I am totally blank. sorry for being a little slow. How does $F_{n+2}=F_{n}+F_{n+1}$ imply the second formula?

Comment: @Tmm See my edit

Comment: @ angryavian thank you for your wonderful details. I understand all the algebra now. However, I am still a little shaky about the relationship between $F_{n}+F_{n+1}$ and $x^{2}f(x)+xf(x)$

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-ax)^{-1}-(1-bx)^{-1}=\dfrac{x(a-b)}{1-(a+b)x+abx^2}$$

Now the $r$th term of $(1-ax)^{-1}$ is $$(ax)^r$$

So, the coefficient of $x^n$ will be $$a^n-b^n$$

Here $a+b=1, ab=-1$

Answer (score 0):

Your comments on angryavian's answer suggest that it would be worth showing some more intermediate steps. Given $f(x) = F_0 + F_1 x + F_2 x^2 + F_3 x^3 + \ldots$ we have $$\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) = & F_0 + & F_1 x + & F_2 x^2 + F_3 x^3 + F_4 x^4 + F_5 x^5 + \ldots \\
  xf(x) = & & F_0 x + & F_1 x^2 + F_2 x^3 + F_3 x^4 + F_4 x^5 + \ldots \\
  x^2f(x) = & & & F_0 x^2 + F_1 x^3 + F_2 x^4 + F_3 x^5 + \ldots \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

whence

$$f(x) - xf(x) - x^2f(x) = F_0 + (F_1 - F_0) x + (F_2 - F_1 - F_0) x^2 + (F_3 - F_2 - F_1) x^3 + \ldots$$

But since $F_{i+2} = F_{i+1} + F_i$ that simplifies to $$f(x) - xf(x) - x^2f(x) = F_0 + (F_1 - F_0) x$$ which is easily rearranged to $$f(x) = \frac{F_0 + (F_1-F_0)x}{1-x-x^2}$$